# WebStorm autocomplete for npm modues

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webstorm

I recently started following a course about Node.js. I have an issue in WebStorm. I am trying to explore the `validator` module. The autocomplete in WebStorm doesn't give me choices for methods unless I select the `default` in the drop-down list which is unusual across all programming languages including JS !!! is it an issue and if yes what is the solution?

[image: Ws-image 1]

[image]

Comment: while importing instead of `const valid = require("validator")` use `const valid = require("validator").default`.

Answer (score 1):

The problems occur because of the weird way properties are defined.
Normally [installing Typescript stubs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.1/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files) can be used as a workaround. But this doesn't work for validator due to [WEB-43528](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43528). Please follow this ticket for updates

Using `import validator from "./validator";` instead of `require()` can be used as a workaround